# Using Perl for taking command inputs

Tags: linux, perl, debian

I'm having trouble with Perl reading in the output of a command.

The command in question: `ps | grep |`

I am trying to execute a script like this:

```
ps  | grep  | script.pl
```

where the output of "`ps  | grep |` " will be used as input for the script to print out the status and its corresponding command.

Output:

```
0    command1
1    command2
....
```

I know in bash you can access an argument to be used as input by using "$#".
Where # corresponds to its position in the command line. No clue in Perl.

Comment: You can use Perl System() function. read here - https://gssg.stanford.edu/public/systemfunction.html

Answer (score 4):

`<>` is short for `<ARGV>`. `ARGV` is a magical handle that reads from the files named by the elements of `@ARGV`, or from `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty (as is the case here). So all you need to do is read using `<>`.

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   print "Got <$_>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ps aux | grep pts | ./script.pl
Got <ikegami  22570  0.0  0.0 101028  3460 ?        S    Nov07   0:02 sshd: ikegami@pts/2 >
Got <ikegami  22571  0.0  0.0 129928  3456 pts/2    Ss   Nov07   0:00 -bash>
Got <ikegami  22865  0.0  0.0 127240  2432 pts/2    R+   18:12   0:00 ps aux>
Got <ikegami  22866  0.0  0.0 120540  2160 pts/2    S+   18:12   0:00 grep pts>
Got <ikegami  22867  0.0  0.0 129604  3928 pts/2    R+   18:12   0:00 /usr/bin/perl ./script.pl>
```

All that's left is to extract the information you want from the data you read in. Of course, you could simply use

```
ps ah -o tty,command
```